# how to use yii -extension - runaction

Tags: yii

I have many functions to get information about local computer :Mac address, Ip address, OS,..etc.They take exceed the  normal time.

I'm trying to use runactions extension,but it didn't work ,i might missing something (and im not sure where have to use  ERunActions::touchUrl). I need help if anybody tried this extension.

This action that called the functions in mycontroller:

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
      if (ERunActions::runBackground())
    {

$mac = $this->getMac();
$ipcomp = $this->getIpcomp();
$oscomp = $this->getOS();
$speed_intertnet =$this-> getSpeafterte();
$ram_size =$this-> getRamsize();
$used_ram =$this-> getUsedram();


}
```

and I used:

```
Yii::import('ext.runactions.components.ERunActions');
```

Comment: Don't you get any error message?

Comment: No, Is there any suggestion?

Comment: well.. I found a syntaxical error in your code. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure this would be the answer, but I noticed that you're missing closing "}".

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    if (ERunActions::runBackground())
    {
        $mac = $this->getMac();
        $ipcomp = $this->getIpcomp();
        $oscomp = $this->getOS();
        $speed_intertnet =$this-> getSpeafterte();
        $ram_size =$this-> getRamsize();
        $used_ram =$this-> getUsedram();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but this only apart :

Comment: public function actionCreate()
 {
       if (ERunActions::runBackground())
        {
$mac = $this->getMac();
$ipcomp = $this->getIpcomp();
$oscomp = $this->getOS();
$speed_intertnet =$this-> getSpeafterte();
$ram_size =$this-> getRamsize();
$used_ram =$this-> getUsedram();
$avai_ram=$ram_size-$used_ram;

}


else
{
 echo 'not working ';
} }

Comment: Anybody can help,I really need to make it work, Is there any other way?